# problem facing while importing python netsnmp module on centos 6

Tags: python, net-snmp

I am getting "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" error while building the netsnmp python code

```
[root@localhost shailendra]# pwd
/root/shailendra
[root@localhost shailendra]# wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp/5.8/net-snmp-5.8.tar.gz/download
[root@localhost shailendra]# tar -zxvf net-snmp-5.8.tar.gz
[root@localhost shailendra]# cd net-snmp-5.8
[root@localhost net-snmp-5.8]#./configure 
[root@localhost net-snmp-5.8]# make
[root@localhost net-snmp-5.8]# make install
[root@localhost net-snmp-5.8]# cd python
[root@localhost python]# python setup.py build
  File "setup.py", line 14
    sys.argv.remove(arg)
                       ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
[root@localhost python]#
[root@localhost python]# cd ~
[root@localhost ~]# python
Python 3.6.3 (default, Jul 31 2018, 03:11:06)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import netsnmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netsnmp'
>>>
```

How to fix the issue

Comment: [Follow this instruction to install the net-snmp](https://www.maketecheasier.com/net-snmp-part-1/)

Comment: Followed below instructions and it worked.                                                       [root@localhost shailendra]# pip install netsnmp-py==0.3                                                  
[root@localhost shailendra]# python
Python 3.6.3 (default, Jul 31 2018, 03:11:06)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import netsnmp
>>>

Comment: Did your problem solve?

Comment: yes its been fixed